# Spreadsheet with ability to do scientific and statistical computation?

Tags: gratis, python, r, spreadsheet

Is there a spreadsheet program that allows scripting with Sagemath, Python and R? I have learned those and found that some things can be done much easier with those than VBA or Libre Office basic. Or is it easier to learn some Python library that edits Excel files?

Comment: Not so much that it's easier to *learn* but rather vastly easier to *find* ways to work with Excel using alternative means, rather than finding completely alternative spreadsheet programs that just so happen to meet your needs. First thing I would look into is [xlwings](https://www.xlwings.org/). Note that "scripting Excel" (i.e. controlling a running instance of the Excel program itself) and "editing Excel files" are two completely different things. Most people have trouble understanding this, but it's much less frustrating if you keep this difference in mind.